# Adding Trigger to cloned sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have Spreadsheet (A). It has a function that clones Spreadsheet (B)  which gives me Spreadsheet (c). This all works just fine.

What I am unable to do is add a trigger to the cloned sheet (c). Every time I run the code below it adds the trigger to (A) instead of (c).

```
// clones the Vendor sheet
function CloneGoogleSheet(vId) {
  // get the destination folder
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1WjgtigSawcsNfwOlGzzEn6jAxrJ0eOu6");
  // copy the spreadsheet
  var vFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1LqK419qWd8ufz7BN3rvalwJYAxybgeWmkJEce0CGUKI").makeCopy("Vendor" + vId, destFolder);
  // get the ID of the new spreadsheet
  var vFileId = vFile.getId();
  // get the new spreadsheet
  var vSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(vFileId);

  // add a new OnEdit trigger to the new spreadsheet
  var vTrigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("SubmitFunction").forSpreadsheet(vFileId).onEdit().create();
}
```

I've tried putting a number of different things in place of 'vFileId' in the ...forSpreadsheet(vFileId)... part of the code.

I've even tried moving the trigger creation into a whole different function. It always creates the trigger on the active spreadsheet, not on the cloned spreadsheet.

Comment: try adding the last line to a function in the cloned sheet with Apps Script API and execute it using Apps Script API

Comment: @Cooper will this require that whoever uses the newly created sheet will have to grant permissions for it?

Comment: I think that's a good thing